# How to read the elven on the 3rd edition Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting cover?

Tags: forgotten-realms, dnd-3e, languages, books, art

The cover for the book in question has inscriptions in the [espruar](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Espruar) [script](https://omniglot.com/conscripts/espruar.htm) on its outer circle. According to one of the authors, it means: *“We remember cities now in ruin and forests murdered, yet still we sing to the stars and hope for renewal.*”

I’m trying to find out what it says (as in, identifying the letters with the ones in the espruar script). Does anyone have a copy of the book, or a good quality image that they can read?

Comment: Here is a picture of the cover: https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/forgottenrealms/images/b/b5/FRCS.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20180326195631 taken from http://forum.candlekeep.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=23362

Comment: I don’t have the original source for the quote, but I’ve found the translation on different forums online. Thanks for the picture! I’ll try to decipher it, then I’ll post it and maybe others can help.

Comment: To confirm, this question's essentially asking *Is there a pronunciation guide for the Elven language?* Then the body asks specifically how to pronounce the text on the *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting* cover. Is that accurate?

Comment: @Hey I Can Chan, no, the letters in elven spell something out: words in elven. I want to know if anyone can read what’s written (as in identity each and every character on the outer circle). The point being that despite the resolution of the picture, the letters are still hard to read (this is why I prefer the original Espruar, which is now the 5e version), and I wanted to know if anyone can identify them.

Comment: Okay. Cool. I'm sorry. I think it's the word *pronounced* in the question that's distracting me. Let me try again: This question asks for answers to A) transcribe the symbols on the *FRCS* cover then B) translate symbol-by-symbol the cover's symbols from Elven into English. The question is *not* asking for the Elven pronunciation of the words on the cover. Is *that* accurate? (If it is, it might be worth including some context—e.g. you're confirming that the author's translation is accurate, you're trying to learn how to write in Elven, or whatever.)

Comment: That is accurate, I forgot that I wrote “pronounce” in the body, this has been changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments I found on various forums, I decided to try comparing the letters to a phrase in English: **we remember cities now in ruin and forests murdered, yet still we sing to the stars and hope for renewal.** The result was disappointing: that’s what’s written in the espruar script!

It’s true, try it for yourself, although there are a few errors (one extra letter on “ruin”, and missing the “h” in “the”), the message reads, in English, but written with espruar letters:

> we remember cities now in ruin and forests murdered, yet still we sing to the stars and hope for renewal